# Python -- unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 62 while inserting data into DB

Tags: python, pymysql

```
Error
{
    "errorMessage": "unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 62",
    "errorType": "ValueError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 66, in lambda_handler\n    mycursor.execute( sqlQuery, values )\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/pymysql/cursors.py\", line 168, in execute\n    query = self.mogrify(query, args)\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/pymysql/cursors.py\", line 147, in mogrify\n    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)\n"
    ]
}

code -
used - pymysql.cursors

record = {
"invoice_id" : "1123",
    "order_number" : "22",
    "rule" : "mf",
    "discount%" : "12",
    "approval_type" : "ase",
    "approval_stage" : "single",
    "approval_role" : "insepector",
    "approval_email" : "babp.com",
        "escalate_to" : "12",
        "escalator_role" : "21",
        "escalator_email" : "213",
        "noapproval_days" : "12",
        "comments" : "eddd",
        "cost_centre_type" : "f"
}

try:
    with mydb.cursor() as mycursor:

        sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO invoice (invoice_id, order_number, rule, discount%, " \
                   "approval_type,approval_stage, approval_role, approval_email," \
                   " escalate_to, escalator_role, escalator_email, noapproval_days, comments," \
                   " cost_centre_type) VALUES (%i, %i, %s, %f, %s," \
                   " %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %i, %s, %s)"

        values = (record["invoice_id"], record["order_number"], record["rule"], record["discount%"], record["approval_type"],
                  record["approval_stage"], record["approval_role"], record["approval_email"], record["escalate_to"],
                  record["escalator_role"], record["escalator_email"], record["noapproval_days"], record["comments"],
                  record["cost_centre_type"])

        mycursor.execute( sqlQuery,values )
        mydb.commit()
finally:
    mydb.close()
```

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with the % after discount. If you remove that, does it help?

Comment: In a format string `%` introduces a format character like `%s` - but where you have `discount%,` the `,` isn't a valid format character. Either remove the % or turn it into `discount%%,` (which formatting will replace `%%` with a single `%`). If in doubt, print `sqlQuery` and check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.