# SQL Query formatting Error: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 286")) in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm executing the SQL query in python code. This query is works properly while using in DB Browser of SQLite, this  when I try use in python it shows error like below:

```
 Error: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 286")) in python .
```

Here query:

```
query = "Select * from ( select detection_class, detection_class_id, matched_alert_id, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, frame_id "\
                " from matched_alert "\
                " where stream_id = '863b1675269e4600ab52a2cf0c418edc' "\
                " ) "\
                " where (SELECT ',' || detection_class || ',' FROM alerts WHERE alert_id=4 ) LIKE  '%,' || detection_class || ',%' "
```

This is execute as:

```
        place_holders = [stream_id, alert_id]  
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, place_holders)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I tried various answers of related question but not working.
how can I solve this problem, any one suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer guys, In a format string % introduces a format character like %s - but where you have `'%,'` or `',%'` the `,` isn't a valid format character. so, for this I use instead of `'%,'` I use `'%%,'` and `',%%'` and it works perfectly.

For mero description answer is in this question

[Python -- unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 62 while inserting data into DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554792/python-unsupported-format-character-0x2c-at-index-62-while-inserting-da)

Comment: You should never use %s placeholders to pass parameters when constructing a query. Format strings are not safe. Always use `?` placeholders.

Comment: yes bro, thank you very much for your help. I never see people big-hearted men like you. You are very helpful thank you ...